# Matlab Struct Manipulation

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I have a struct, D

```
    whos D
    Name      Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes
    D         1x128            93372  struct
```

Opening up the variable from the workspace, I have 128 <1x1 struct> fields. How can I delete, for example, all elements of the 3rd, 11th and 100th substructure, so that I am left with a smaller version of D, of size 1x125?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a muppet. To delete the 10th element, simply:

```
    D(:,10)=[];
```

Apologies for the unnecessary question!